# application crashes at a click of a button but not on the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, crash

On the IOS simulator on Xcode the application runs fine with no crashes, but when I put it on to my iPhone and click this certain button the application crashes even though all the other buttons do make the application crash.

I don't have the crash log report as I am not a registered developer, I have a jailbroken device. The code in the button basically checks if there are any illegal characters in the textfields or if the "hours" text field is over 24, gets the hours field and coverts it to seconds, and sees to check if the timer has already been started and if so then resume and if not just start.

`Calc_Start` is the actual button, update is the method that gets called when the timer has been started. There is nothing linked up in the interface builder wrong because it works fine in the simulator. I would just appreciate it if someone could see if there was anything in my code that was making the application crash.

If possible could anyone tell me how to get a "fake" or third party console application for iPhone so that I can see the crash reports because I do not want to get a developer account due to the fact I never want to put my apps into the app store, it is just a hobby for me.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)Calc_Start:(id)sender
{
    float b = [self.tf1.text floatValue];
    float bb = [self.tf2.text floatValue];

    if (b > 24)
    {
        self.tf1.text = @"24";
    }
    if (bb > 24)
    {
        self.tf2.text = @"24";
    }

    if ([self.tf1.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.tf1.text = @"0";
    }
    if ([self.tf2.text isEqualToString:@""]) // if any of the text fields are empty, add 0's to them
    {
        self.tf2.text = @"0";
    }
    if ([self.tf3.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.tf3.text = @"0";
    }
    if ([self.tf4.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.tf4.text = @"100";
    }

    if ([self.tf1.text containsString:@"-"])
    {
        self.tf1.text = [self.tf1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    }
    if ([self.tf2.text containsString:@"-"])
    {
        self.tf2.text = [self.tf2.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    }
    if ([self.tf3.text containsString:@"-"])
    {
        self.tf3.text = [self.tf3.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]; // if any of the text fields have a "-" in them then get rid of them
    }
    if ([self.tf4.text containsString:@"-"])
    {
        self.tf4.text = [self.tf4.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    }


    float i = [self.tf1.text floatValue];
    float ii = [self.tf2.text floatValue];
    float iii = [self.tf3.text floatValue]; // gets the integer value of the strings inside the text fields
    float iv = [self.tf4.text floatValue];

    float secondCount = i * 3600;               // converts the first 2 to seconds to be used in the timer
    float ubsecondCount = ii * 3600;

    if ([self.countdown_label.text  isEqual: @"00:00:00"])
    {
        secondsLeft = secondCount - ubsecondCount; // used in the update method
    }
    else
    {
        secondsLeft = savedSeconds;
    }

    perSecondd = (iii * (iv/100))/3600;
    NSString *prSecond = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%.5f", perSecondd];

    float perMinutee = (iii * (iv/100))/60;
    NSString *prMinute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.3f", perMinutee];

    self.perSecond.text = prSecond;
    self.perMinute.text = prMinute;

    if (![self.tf1.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        if (![timer isValid])
        {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(update)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:true];

            [self.calc_button_atr setTitle: @"Calculate / Stop"
                                  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [timer invalidate];
            [self.calc_button_atr setTitle: @"Calculate / Start"
                              forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}

- (void) update
{
    if(secondsLeft > 0 )
    {
        secondsLeft--;
        int hours = secondsLeft / 3600;
        int minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60;
        int seconds = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60;
        self.countdown_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds];

        p = p + perSecondd;
        NSString *prSec = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%.5f", p];
        self.mps.text = prSec;

        savedSeconds = secondsLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self.calc_button_atr setTitle:@"Calculate / Start"
                              forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

and here is the crash report:

```
015-01-06 15:04:44.703 Your Pay Per Second[10612:60b] -[__NSCFString containsString:]:      unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1558ffc0
2015-01-06 15:04:44.712 Your Pay Per Second[10612:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized  selector sent to instance 0x1558ffc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d746f83 0x37ecaccf 0x2d74a917 0x2d749203 0x2d698768 0x86f8b 0x2ff99037 0x2ff98fd7 0x2ff98fb1     0x2ff84717 0x2ff98a2f 0x2ff98701 0x2ff936cb 0x2ff688cd 0x2ff66f77 0x2d71220b 0x2d7116db 0x2d70fecf  0x2d67aebf 0x2d67aca3 0x32580663 0x2ffc714d 0x89511 0x383d7ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Without details about the crash (error message and the specific line causing the problem), it's hard to help you.

Comment: Please fix all of your variable names such as i, ii, iii, iv, it would really make it easier for someone to understand your code and perhaps help with a crash.

Comment: sorry. the i,ii,iii,iv are just values that i got from the 4 textfields from inside the application. which are hours worked (i), breaks (ii) , hourly pay (iii) and to see if they have a public holiday rate (iv). and another stupid variable is the p one, i just used that because it wouldn't let me add the perSecondd variable to itself and when i tried to apply it to the NSString it would display the old variable.

Comment: You can't develop iOS apps and either install them on a (non jailbroken) device or submit them to the app store unless you buy a developer's license.

Comment: Just use the names: `hoursWorked`, `breaks`, `hourlyPay`, `publicHolidayRate` and `perSecondd`. The point is to make it easy for a person to understand. It also makes it easier to get the code to work. While you are at it replace `tf1`, `tf2`, `tf3`, `tf4` with more descriptive names.

Comment: hey i found a way to fake code sign ill put the error in the question

Comment: any way i figured it out it just didn't like the contains string: can someone tell me why and how to fix it. thanks

Comment: You want to check that it contains the string '-' or not right?

Comment: Put a exception break point then point out the exact line then post that line

Comment: yeah i wanted to see if it contained the string '-' but it doesn't matter i figured it out haha apparently containsString: belongs to iOS8 and I'm building for iOS7 so instead of the containsString i put this:

    [self.tf1.text rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound
thanks for your help any way people

Comment: Can you plz correct my answer if it was right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your crash is the **containsString** method.

This method is introduced in iOS 8 and it might be possible that you're running your app in iOS 8 simulator and your device is running on iOS 7.

So for iOS 7, you'll need to use

```
if ([self.tf1.text rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound) {
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you, just replace your code:

```
if ([self.tf1.text containsString:@"-"])
{
    self.tf1.text = [self.tf1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
}
```

with this code:

```
if ([self.tf1.text rangeOfString:@"-"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"String is found");
        NSLog(@"text %@",self.tf1.text);
        self.tf1.text = [self.tf1.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    }
```

And you are done!!!
All the best...!!!